# How to check if number has a decimal?

Tags: ruby

I want to specifically check if a given number contains ".5"

I'm only dealing with whole numbers and halves (0.5, 1, 1.5, etc).

Comment: 4 downvotes without a comment?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

#### `%` should work

```
variable % 1 != 0
```

Check this [RubyFiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/52f7b/).

*Here is a [JavaScript fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VmSfB/1), too.*

Comment: @Melki sorry i did not follow you

Comment: @karthilkr He wants only the number with `.5` if you take `a = 1.2` you will have `1.2 % 1 != 0` but there is no `.5` in `1.2`

Comment: The OP is dealing with whole numbers, and .5 - so this would hold true. If he needed to validate <b>only</b> `.5` or whole numbers, then the answer would be different.

Comment: Yes but in order to help all the communauty it's better to provide a general solution. (what does OP mean ?).

Comment: @Melki  OP means original poster.

Comment: Though this works for OP who is only dealing with `.5`, this could fail for others due to floating point rounding error. E.g. `1.000000000000000001 % 1 == 0`

Comment: My problem with this as the best answer is that it lacks an explanation. A good answer should include an explanation too.

Answer (score 13):

Always use [`BigDecimal`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) to check the fractional part of a number to avoid [floating point errors](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html):

```
require 'bigdecimal'

BigDecimal.new(number).frac == BigDecimal("0.5")
```

For example:

```
BigDecimal.new("0.5").frac == BigDecimal("0.5")
# => true

BigDecimal.new("1.0").frac == BigDecimal("0.5")
# => false
```

And a more general solution to see if a number is whole:

```
BigDecimal.new("1.000000000000000000000000000000000000000001").frac.zero?
# => false
```

Comment: Good for introducing to a new library.  :)

Answer (score 7):

`myValue == myValue.floor`

or if you really want to check specifically for 0.5, 1.5 etc

`myValue - myValue.floor == 0.5`

Comment: Ha, your answer didn't even require knowledge of ruby. xD +1

Comment: Floats are inexact: `1.3 - 1 == 0.3 # => false`

Comment: 1.5 - 1 == 0.5 though, as asked in the question

Comment: Though this works for OP who is only dealing with .5, this could fail for others when dealing with greater precision due to floating point rounding error.

Answer (score 1):

```
(2.50).to_s.include?('.5') #=> true
(2).to_s.include?('.5') #=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with_decimal = 1.5
without_decimal = 2
```

You can check if the number is the same when you change it to integer.

```
Integer(with_decimal) != with_decimal
# => true


Integer(without_decimal) != without_decimal
# => false
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
n = 1.5
# => 1.5

n - Integer(n) == 0.5
# => true
```